# public key in ios keychain changes on each get

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption

I have followed the apple developer documents and specifically the examples showing how to generate key pair, encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key. They have three example methods in the guide for this (page 19 onwards [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/CertKeyTrustProgGuide.pdf)).

I have copied an pasted these three methods into my project, only changing them to be public class methods, added logging and hooked up buttons to call them feeding the output of the encryption into the decrypt:

In the viewcontroller:

```
-(IBAction)generateKey:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [CryptoClass generateKeyPairPlease];
}

-(IBAction)encryptAndDecrypt
{
    NSData *data = [CryptoClass encryptWithPublicKey]; 
    [CryptoClass decryptWithPrivateKey:data];
}
```

The code for the three methods are:

```
static const UInt8 publicKeyIdentifier[] = "com.apple.sample.publickey\0";
static const UInt8 privateKeyIdentifier[] = "com.apple.sample.privatekey\0";

+ (NSData *)encryptWithPublicKey
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    size_t cipherBufferSize;
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer;                     // 1

    // [cipherBufferSize]
    const uint8_t dataToEncrypt[] = "the quick brown fox jumps "
    "over the lazy dog\0"; // 2
    size_t dataLength = sizeof(dataToEncrypt)/sizeof(dataToEncrypt[0]);

    SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;                                 // 3

    NSData * publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier
                                        length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)]; // 4

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // 5

    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
    // 6

    status = SecItemCopyMatching
    ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey); // 7

    //  Allocate a buffer

    cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);

    //  Error handling

    if (cipherBufferSize < sizeof(dataToEncrypt)) {
        // Ordinarily, you would split the data up into blocks
        // equal to cipherBufferSize, with the last block being
        // shorter. For simplicity, this example assumes that
        // the data is short enough to fit.
        printf("Could not decrypt.  Packet too large.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Encrypt using the public.
    status = SecKeyEncrypt(    publicKey,
                           kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                           dataToEncrypt,
                           (size_t) dataLength,
                           cipherBuffer,
                           &cipherBufferSize
                           );                              // 8

    //  Error handling
    //  Store or transmit the encrypted text

    if (publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:dataLength];

    free(cipherBuffer);

    return encryptedData;
}


+ (void)generateKeyPairPlease
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    NSMutableDictionary *privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // 2

    NSData * publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier
                                        length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)];
    NSData * privateTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:privateKeyIdentifier
                                         length:strlen((const char *)privateKeyIdentifier)];
    // 3

    SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;
    SecKeyRef privateKey = NULL;                                // 4

    [keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
                    forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType]; // 5
    [keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1024]
                    forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits]; // 6

    [privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                       forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent]; // 7
    [privateKeyAttr setObject:privateTag
                       forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag]; // 8

    [publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                      forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent]; // 9
    [publicKeyAttr setObject:publicTag
                      forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag]; // 10

    [keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr
                    forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs]; // 11
    [keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr
                    forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs]; // 12

    status = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr,
                                &publicKey, &privateKey); // 13
    //    error handling...


    if(publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);
    if(privateKey) CFRelease(privateKey);                       // 14
}

+ (void)decryptWithPrivateKey: (NSData *)dataToDecrypt
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    size_t cipherBufferSize = [dataToDecrypt length];
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (uint8_t *)[dataToDecrypt bytes];

    size_t plainBufferSize;
    uint8_t *plainBuffer;

    SecKeyRef privateKey = NULL;

    NSData * privateTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:privateKeyIdentifier
                                         length:strlen((const char *)privateKeyIdentifier)];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPrivateKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the private key query dictionary.
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
    // 1

    status = SecItemCopyMatching
    ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPrivateKey, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey); // 2

    //  Allocate the buffer
    plainBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey);
    plainBuffer = malloc(plainBufferSize);

    if (plainBufferSize < cipherBufferSize) {
        // Ordinarily, you would split the data up into blocks
        // equal to plainBufferSize, with the last block being
        // shorter. For simplicity, this example assumes that
        // the data is short enough to fit.
        printf("Could not decrypt.  Packet too large.\n");
        return;
    }

    //  Error handling

    status = SecKeyDecrypt(    privateKey,
                           kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                           cipherBuffer,
                           cipherBufferSize,
                           plainBuffer,
                           &plainBufferSize
                           );                              // 3

    //  Error handling
    //  Store or display the decrypted text
    NSLog(@"Plain: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)plainBuffer]);
    if(privateKey) CFRelease(privateKey);
}
```

I have been trying many different guides and read a lot of posts here trying to get this to work. I also tried Apples KeyChainWrapperItem to store and retrieve the keys with no luck. I also found a post here describing and showing the exact code to get the key in data-format, but that returns nil for some reason.

The last thing I did was using Matt Gallagher's NSData+Base64 category to print the encrypted string and can visually see that the string is wildly different for each pass even if I do not generate a new key with this code:

```
-(IBAction)encryptAndDecrypt
{
    NSData *data = [CryptoClass encryptWithPublicKey]; 
    NSLog(@"String: %@", [data base64EncodedString]); // Print encrypted data as base64
    [CryptoClass decryptWithPrivateKey:data];
}
```

FYI I'm currently only running on the simulator if that is of importance. And I reset it to clear the keychain before each generation.

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Errors in provided code**

In `+ (NSData *)encryptWithPublicKey`, this line will strip the encrypted data (and destroy it)

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:dataLength];
```

It should be

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
```

**Different result each time**

It is not an error to see different results each time. The PKCS#1 encryption algorithm uses some random seed to make the cipher-text different each time. This is called padding and  protects against several attacks, e.g. frequency analysis and ciphertext matching. See this Wikipedia article section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Padding_schemes